# create an array from JSON in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am trying to convert JSON data into an array but I do not really have any idea how to do it.

I get the data and save it in strings and I can also show it on display.

```
struct User_Hosting: Codable {
    let company_name: String
    let website: String
    let street: String
    let housenumber: String
    let zip: String
    let city: String    

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case company_name = "company_name"
        case website = "website"
        case street = "street"
        case housenumber = "housenumber"
        case zip = "zip"
        case city = "city"
    }
}
```

And here some other codes:

```
let url = URL(string: "myURL.com")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "An error occurred")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.dataSource = try! JSONDecoder().decode([User_Hosting].self, from: data)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `CodingKeys` when struct's property names and property names from server are identical

Comment: Add the `JSON response` that you're getting from API.

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi Well, I did not know it can work without CodingKeys... Thanks!

Comment: And what is your `dataSource` property  in `self?.dataSource = try! JSONDecoder().decode([User_Hosting].self, from: data)`?

Comment: In Swift we prefer Camel Case (camelCase) over Snake Case (snake_case). So, you can use this line `let decoder = JSONDecoder() decoder.decordingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase` and then use `let company_name as let companyName`.

Comment: Don’t do `try!`, use a proper `do {...} catch { print(error) }` so you don’t miss any errors that might happen during decoding. The answer to your question might very well be in that print statement. And do the decoding before `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi what do you mean with dataSource property?

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your help! But where should I use that code?

Comment: I don't think there is any use of `DispatchQueue.main.async` here as you are not updating any UI component

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi I am using it for TableView. I don not know if this is the right answer.

Comment: I don't think that's how it works, you need to **update the array** that you are using to populate the `tableView` from and **not the dataSource itself**

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi I want to put alphabetical index on right side of a UITableview and only sort company name on it, but I do not know which array is having the data.

Comment: @AmedLMAB As I already said, you can use it above decoding from your Codable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CodingKeys` match the property names, so you can get rid of the `enum` at all

```
struct UserHosting: Codable {
    let companyName: String
    let website: String
    let street: String
    let housenumber: String
    let zip: String
    let city: String    
}
```

Since you have a some snake case keys in JSON, you can change the JSONDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy to `convertFromSnakeCase`, like so

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

Above decoder will treat keys such as `company_name` to be assigned to `companyName` property of your struct.

Finally you can decode your JSON in a `do-catch` block, so in case of an error we will have a message as to what went wrong.

```
do {
    self.dataSource = try decoder.decode([UserHosting].self, from: data)
} catch {
    print("JSON Decoding Error \(error)")
}
```

Comment: As have been pointed out many times before, _do not_ use localizedDescription do `print(error)` instead for a much more detailed  error message

Comment: @AamirRq I want to put alphabetical index on right side of a UITableview and only sort company name on it, but I do not know which array is having the data.